# Optimal bet given a repeated coin flip game

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance, gambling

A brainteaser question obtained from [here](http://www.decal.org/file/2945) states:

> Flip 10000 fair coins. You are offered a 1-1 bet that the sum is less than 5000. You can bet 1, 2, ..., 100
>   dollars. How much will you bet. How much will you bet if someone tells you that the sum of the coins is
>   less than 5100?

I believe that maximizing the expected value would give you 100 for the first situation because there are 5001 win cases and 5000 loss cases, and betting 1 (the minimum) in the second case because now the probability of losing is greater than 0.5.

However the question of "how much will you bet" is ambiguous to me. Is expected value the right metric for betting? Are there other reasonable metrics to consider before making a bet?

Comment: Writing "How much will you bet" without stating an explicit goal is a bad formulation, if nothing else (and makes it into a psychology problem rather than a math problem). You should be told what you're after in a problem like this. One can assume that you want to get as rich as possible, but risk aversion is a very human thing, so I don't think many would actually bet 100 dollars.

Comment: I guess my real question is "what else could i consider mathematically" to help me to determine what to bet.

Comment: The Kelly criterion will give a useful suggestion of what proportion of your assets you should bet on a gamble with a positive expected return, though some people find it a little aggressive for their tastes.  The binomial distribution (possibly with a normal approximation) could tell you what the conditional probability is

Comment: What is “the sum of the coins”?

Comment: I assumed "the sum of the coins" to mean the number of heads obtained from 10000 flips of a fair coin.

Comment: Sum of the coins is the sum of all the outcomes assuming heads counts as 1 and tails as 0

Answer (score 1):

Let's think about the problem with fewer coins, say 10. It is the same problem as if you had 1 fair coin with 10 flips. For 10 coins with 2 sides each there are $2^{10}$ possible outcomes. The number of ways to get exactly 4 heads from 10 is the binomial coefficient, 10C4 = 210. Dividing 210 by 1024, we get 20.5%. Now what's the probability that there are less than 5 heads? Sum up the binomial coefficients for $n < 5$ and divide by all potential outcomes, 210. That gives us 37.7%.

Now we can introduce the notion of expected value. You have a probability of 0.377 of the number of heads being less than 5, for 10 flips. That means there is a (1-0.377) probability of there being 5 or more heads. How much can you expect to make from betting $X$ dollars that there are less than 5 heads? That is simply the sum of the dollar amount associated with each of your probabilities. You've got X for 0.377, and you've got $-X$ for (1-0.377). The expected value is then $0.377X-X+0.377X=-0.246X$.

Whatever $X$ you have, you should expect to lose 24.6% of it!

Using Wolfram Alpha to solve the problem for 10000 coins and less than 5000 heads, you've got a probability of 0.496 of getting your money back. That means on average, you can expect to lose 0.8% of your money X.

For less than 5100 you get a probability of 0.977. That means your expected value is 0.954 and thus you should expect to get your money back plus 95.4% of it. An extra 100 heads of cushion makes this a slam dunk bet, despite intuition.

The correct number to bet depends on your risk tolerance and basically gives insight to your interpretation of risk-reward, given the probability of each outcome. The Kelly Criterion mentioned above could be a useful rule of thumb. Using that, we get 0.977*2-1=95.4% of capital.

Now moving on to the second question: how much will you bet if you are given the information that the sum of the coins is definitely less than 5100. That is a Bayesian conditional probability problem.

You're basically gaining a measurement, and that will affect your probabilities. The formula is given as:

$$
{\rm P}(A | B) = \frac{{\rm P}(B|A){\rm P}(A)}{{\rm P}(B)}.
$$

The formula is actually pretty easy to calculate for this situation. Event A is the probability of getting less than 5000 heads. Event B is the probability of getting less than 5100 heads. The bar means given. So the probaility of A given B is the probability of B given A times ${\rm P}(A)/{\rm P}(B)$. What is the probability of B given A? Well, if it's given that it is less than 5000, then it's certainly less than 5100! So ${\rm P}(B|A) = 1$. Plug in the two values we calculated above: ${\rm P}(A)=0.496$ and ${\rm P}(B)=0.977$. That means ${\rm P}(A|B)=0.508$. So that bit of extra knowledge gives you an edge in the game. If you are doing it a million times, then you can expect a positive return, no matter how much you put up.

Comment: What is 10C4? Do you mean ${10 \choose 4}?$